# Create a event for when data is aviable on a serial port

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to C# and .Net programming, but i am wondering if there is a way to create an event for when data is available on a serial port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the example you need can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx).
I write the example:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

class PortDataReceived
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceviedHandler);

        mySerialPort.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }

    private static void DataReceviedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.Write(indata);
    }
}
```